# Send Email to Assigned In an Activity

Tags: activities

I am creating an activity and assigning it, but would like that to be emailed to the assignee. Is there a way automatically email the person that is assigned on an activity?

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting at Administer/Customize Data and Screens/Display Preferences, a tick box with the description Notify Activity Assignees. Ticking that will send a mail to the assignee.